# How to avoid line breaks at StaffGroup boundaries

Tags: lilypond

I have recently started writing music notation with LilyPond. I find it convenient to split songs into different parts such as prelude, intro, interlude etc. So I have:

```
%prelude.ly
\new StaffGroup <<
  \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f

  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Piano"
    shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
  } \new Voice \relative c'' {
    c d e f
  }
>>
```

and

```
%intro.ly
\new StaffGroup <<
  \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f

  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Piano"
    shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
  } \new Voice \relative c'' {
    g a b c
  }
>>
```

Then I combine everything like so:

```
<<
  \chords {
    c,2 g,2 c,2 f,2 g,2 f,2 g,2 c,2
  }

  {
    \include "prelude.ly"
    \include "intro.ly"
  }
>>
```

This method works quite well for large scores. Except I get line breaks at `StaffGroup` boundaries as shown below:

[image: Score on a staff that splits horizontally at the boundary between the prelude and the intro]

Questions:

1. Does an average musician find these breaks annoying or are they quite common?
2. How can I avoid these breaks? Would be nice to get rid of the staff symbols at the boundaries as well.
3. Are there better ways of organising large scores?

Update: Answers below have suggested avoiding multiple staffgroups. But if possible I would prefer to have a new staffgroup for each part of score. This allows me the felxibility to add more instruments in parallel to a particular part without affecting anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code essentially evaluates to something like

```
{
  %prelude.ly
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f

    \new Staff \with {
      instrumentName = "Piano"
      shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
    } \new Voice \relative c'' {
      c d e f
    }
  >>
  
  %intro.ly
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f

    \new Staff \with {
      instrumentName = "Piano"
      shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
    } \new Voice \relative c'' {
      g a b c
    }
  >>
}
```

You see that you are calling `\new StaffGroup` and `\new Staff` multiple times. This means that at the point in question Lilypond will simply create a new context, which is by default placed below the currently existing context. To achieve what you want you should not use `\new ContextType`, but `\context ContextType = contextID`. This will attempt to find a context of given type and ID (if nothing found a new context is created) and will switch to that context. So if you do

```
{
  %prelude.ly
  \context StaffGroup = "SG1" <<
    \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f

    \context Staff = "Staff1" \with {
      instrumentName = "Piano"
      shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
    } \new Voice \relative c'' {
      c d e f
    }
  >>
  
  %intro.ly
  \context StaffGroup = "SG1" <<
    \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f

    \context Staff = "Staff1" \with {
      instrumentName = "Piano"
      shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
    } \new Voice \relative c'' {
      g a b c
    }
  >>
}
```

it works as you intend. In fact you can even outsource the chordnames into the separate files:

```
{
  %prelude.ly
  <<
    \context ChordNames = "CN" \chordmode {
      c,2 g,2 c,2 f,2
    }
    \context StaffGroup = "SG1" <<
      \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f
  
      \context Staff = "Staff1" \with {
        instrumentName = "Piano"
        shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
      } \new Voice \relative c'' {
        c d e f
      }
    >>
  >>
  
  %intro.ly
  <<
    \context ChordNames = "CN" \chordmode {
      g,2 f,2 g,2 c,2
    }
    \context StaffGroup = "SG1" <<
      \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f
  
      \context Staff = "Staff1" \with {
        instrumentName = "Piano"
        shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
      } \new Voice \relative c'' {
        g a b c
      }
    >>
  >>
}
```

Comment: you are awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen anything like that before, it just looks like a mistake.

---

I suggest moving the common parts of your subfiles (`prelude.ly` & `intro.ly`) into the combining file (`combine.ly`), and making variables (`\prelude` & `\intro`) for the music in each of these.

Something like this:

```
%% prelude.ly

\version "2.24.1"

prelude = {
    \relative c'' {
        c2 d e f
    }
}

%\score {
%   \prelude
%}
```

```
%% intro.ly

\version "2.24.1"

intro = {
    \relative c'' {
        g2 a b c
    }
}

%\score {
%   \intro
%}
```

```
%% combine.ly

\version "2.24.1"

\include "prelude.ly"
\include "intro.ly"

<<
    \chords {
        c,2 g, c, f, g, f, g, c,
    }

    \new StaffGroup <<
        \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f

        \new Staff \with {
            instrumentName = "Piano"
            shortInstrumentName = "Pno"
        }
            \new Voice {
                \prelude
                \intro
            }
    >>
>>
```

This will give a "normal looking" score:
[image: Single staff with prelude and intro joined seamlessly]

---

**NB**: When you are working on the subfiles, you'll want to uncomment the `\score` blocks, so that you will be able to see what you are doing (by compiling the subfiles) without having to compile the `combine.ly` file. Re-comment them when you have finished working on the subfiles, so that you don't get duplication in the `combine.ly` file.

Comment: Avoiding multiple staffgroups is the most straightforward solution. But if possible  I would prefer to have a new staffgroup for each part of score. This allows me the felxibility to add more instruments in parallel to a particular part without affecting anything else.

Comment: @kargirwar This comment should be part of your original post so that you get answers relevant to your goals.

Comment: Regarding your NB: Instead you can also do something like wrapping your `\score` blocks in `$(if (or (not (defined? 'INCLUDED)) (not INCLUDED)) #{ \score { ... } #})`. This will create a score unless you’ve done `INCLUDED = ##t`. Thus you won’t have to do any comment/uncomment game but simply have a score created if compiled as single file and not if included (as long as the including file does `INCLUDED = ##t`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider your code in toto:

```
<<                                                                                  
  \chords {                                                                         
    c,2 g,2 c,2 f,2 g,2 f,2 g,2 c,2                                                 
  }                                                                                 
                                                                                    
  {                                                                                 
    %prelude.ly
    \new StaffGroup <<                                                                  
    \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f                             
                                                                                    
    \new Staff \with {                                                                
      instrumentName = "Piano"                                                        
      shortInstrumentName = "Pno"                                                     
    } \new Voice \relative c'' {                                                      
    c d e f                                                                         
    }                                                                                 
  >>
  %intro.ly
  \new StaffGroup <<                                                                  
    \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f                             
                                                                                      
    \new Staff \with {                                                                
      instrumentName = "Piano"                                                        
      shortInstrumentName = "Pno"                                                     
    } \new Voice \relative c'' {                                                      
      g a b c                                                                         
    }                                                                                 
  >> 
  }                                                                                 
>>
```

The image posted in the question is as expected, because a new staff group was started. But this is not what is actually desired. To get the desired result, the complete code should be more like this:

```
<<                                                                                  
  \chords {                                                                         
    c,2 g,2 c,2 f,2 g,2 f,2 g,2 c,2                                                 
  }                                                                                 
                                                                                    
  {                                                                                 
    \new StaffGroup <<                                                                  
    \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f                             
                                                                                    
    \new Staff \with {                                                                
      instrumentName = "Piano"                                                        
      shortInstrumentName = "Pno"                                                     
    } \new Voice \relative c'' {                                                      
      %prelude.ly
      c d e f                                                                         
      %intro.ly
      g a b c                                                                         
    }                                                                                 
  >>
  }
>>
```

Which is to say:

```
<<                                                                                  
  \chords {                                                                         
    c,2 g,2 c,2 f,2 g,2 f,2 g,2 c,2                                                 
  }                                                                                 
                                                                                    
  {                                                                                 
    \new StaffGroup <<                                                                  
    \override StaffGroup.SystemStartBracket.stencil = ##f                             
                                                                                    
    \new Staff \with {                                                                
      instrumentName = "Piano"                                                        
      shortInstrumentName = "Pno"                                                     
    } \new Voice \relative c'' {                                                      
        \include "prelude.ly"                                                           
        \include "intro.ly"                                                             
    }                                                                                 
  >>
  }
>>
```

In which the include files just contain the notes for that part of the piece.